# Adding Alignment to a Manipulate Ouput in Mathematica

Tags: coding-style, alignment, wolfram-mathematica

Considering the following :

```
Manipulate[
           If[Intersection[Row1, Row2] == {}, 
              Style[Plus @@ {Plus @@ Row1, Plus @@ Row2}, Bold, 20],
              "Error"],
{{Row1, {1}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, ControlType -> TogglerBar},
{{Row2, {2}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, ControlType -> TogglerBar}
           ]
```

[image]

**- I would like the "3" to be centered, is it possible ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manipulate has its own Alignment option. You can see if that works for you:

```
Manipulate[

If[Intersection[Row1,Row2]=={},Style[Plus@@{Plus@@Row1,Plus@@Row2},Bold,20],"Error"],   

{{Row1,{1}},{1,2,3,4,5},ControlType->TogglerBar},
{{Row2,{2}},{1,2,3,4,5},ControlType->TogglerBar},

Alignment->Center
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Panel`, with the `Alignment` option:

```
Manipulate[
 Panel[
  If[Intersection[Row1, Row2] == {}, 
     Style[Plus @@ {Plus @@ Row1, Plus @@ Row2}, Bold, 20], "Error"
  ], 
  ImageSize -> 150, Alignment -> Center, Appearance -> "Frameless"
 ], 
 {{Row1, {1}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, ControlType -> TogglerBar},
 {{Row2, {2}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, ControlType -> TogglerBar}
]
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is perfect. Just posted a question on DelaunayTriangulation which is almost addressed to you :)

Comment: would you know why "Center" in your code appears in Red despite working perfectly ?

Comment: I don't see that on my screen. Sure you have copied it faithfully? Previously, the last bracket was misplaced out of the blue code box above. You might have missed that one. But then, the code shouldn't work at all.

Comment: Oh I just understood what is happening : Shadowing in Multiple Contexts !