# Adjust Panel Location in a Manipulate object in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, panel, setter

Building up on [Sjoerd solution to add alignment to a manipulate object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469288/adding-alignment-to-a-manipulate-ouput-in-mathematica) :

Consider the following :

```
Manipulate[
 Panel[Style[Row1, Bold, 20],
   ImageSize -> 150, Alignment -> Center]
 Panel[Style[Row2, Bold, 20],
   ImageSize -> 150, Alignment -> Center],
{{Row1, {1}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, ControlType -> SetterBar,ControlPlacement -> Left},
{{Row2, {2}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, ControlType -> SetterBar,ControlPlacement -> Left}]
```

[image]

**Is there a way to have the panel on top of each other aligned with the corresponding SetterBar ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{SetterBar[Dynamic[Row1], {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}], 
    Panel[Style[Row1, Bold, 20], ImageSize -> 150, 
     Alignment -> Center] }, {SetterBar[
     Dynamic[Row2], {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}], 
    Panel[Style[Row2, Bold, 20], ImageSize -> 150, 
     Alignment -> Center]}}], {{Row1, {1}}, 
  ControlType -> None}, {{Row2, {2}}, ControlType -> None}]
```

[image: manipulate screenshot]

This technically moves the controls into the body of the manipulate, and prevents the actual controls from showing up where they normally would.

Comment: Thank you. The problem I posted was a simplified version of the actual one. I have not yet been able to implement your solution on the "real" one. I have uploaded a simple notebook here : http://www.laeh500.com/LAEH/Panel_Problem.html . Would you have time to look at it, could you let me know if you think it is doable  ? Many thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I actually never got to successfully apply it to my problem. I have used static alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

```
DynamicModule[{Row1 = 1, Row2 = 2},
 Manipulate[
  Grid[
   {
    {
      Control[{Row1, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}],
      Panel[Style[Row1, Bold, 20], ImageSize -> 150,  Alignment -> Center]
    }, 
    {
      Control[{Row2, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}], 
      Panel[Style[Row2, Bold, 20], ImageSize -> 150,  Alignment -> Center]}
    }
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[
  {Panel[Style[Row1, Bold, 20], ImageSize -> {150, 50}, Alignment -> Center] , 
   Panel[Style[Row2, Bold, 20], ImageSize -> {150, 50}, Alignment -> Center]}],
 Column[
 {
 Control@{{Row1,{},Pane["",ImageSize->{0, 50}]},Range@5,ControlType -> SetterBar},
 Control@{{Row2,{},Pane["",ImageSize->{0, 50}]},Range@5,ControlType -> SetterBar}
   }],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]